# How to sum categorical variable across variables

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

My data set looks like this

```
df<-read.table(text="group, race
               1, 1
               1, 1
               1, 4
               2, 1
               2, 3
               2, 4
               3, 1
               2, 1
               1, 1", header=T, sep=",")
```

I would like to get the sum of the count of each race BY each group. I have tried using the aggregate function but to no avail

I hope to have output that looks something like this:

```r
group   race   total
1       1      2
1       4      1
2       1      2
.
.
.
3       1      1
```

Comment: Probably you need `df %>% count(group, race)`

Comment: What do you mean by sum of count? This looks like data where you would count values of each group and race, but I'm not sure what you would then sum. Your output doesn't quite match your data: group 1, race 1 occurs 3 times, not 2

Comment: On earlier version of @akrun comment: ```df %>% add_count(group, race)``` does the same thing that I have with `ave()`.

Comment: `as.data.frame(table(df$group, df$race))`

Comment: @Cath Maybe ```as.data.frame(table(group=df$group, race=df$race))``` or ```as.data.frame(table(df))``` to preserve the names.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in base using `aggregate()`:

```
with(df, aggregate(list(count=race), by=list(group=group,race=race), FUN=length))

#>   group race count
#> 1     1    1     3
#> 2     2    1     2
#> 3     3    1     1
#> 4     2    3     1
#> 5     1    4     1
#> 6     2    4     1
```

or using `ave()` (if you want to preserve your data structure and just add column `total`):

```
df$total <- ave(df$race, df[,c("group","race")], FUN=length)

#>   group race total
#> 1     1    1     3
#> 2     1    1     3
#> 3     1    4     1
#> 4     2    1     2
#> 5     2    3     1
#> 6     2    4     1
#> 7     3    1     1
#> 8     2    1     2
#> 9     1    1     3
```

Comment: or `aggregate(list(count = df$race), df, length)`

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df<-tribble(~"group", ~"race",
               1, 1,
               1, 1,
               1, 4,
               2, 1,
               2, 3,
               2, 4,
               3, 1,
               2, 1,
               1, 1)
df %>% 
    count(group, race)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   group  race     n
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1     1     3
#> 2     1     4     1
#> 3     2     1     2
#> 4     2     3     1
#> 5     2     4     1
#> 6     3     1     1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Similar to dylanjm but slightly different logic:

```
df %>%
group_by(group, race) %>%
summarise(Total = length(race))
```

Yields the same result:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   group [?]
  group  race Total
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     3
2     1     4     1
3     2     1     2
4     2     3     1
5     2     4     1
6     3     1     1
```

Comment: use `length` instead of `sum`!

Comment: Thanks - that's the dangers of multi-tasking.